# How to store token in cookie?

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an API which returns me a token and using that token I am able to make more requests to the API, right now I am storing the token in session however I think using session defeats the entire purpose of using a token so I am wondering how can I store the token in a cookie? Below is the code where I am getting the token and writing it to session:-

```
public async Task<string> GetToken(bool tokenExpired)
{
    if (_context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("token") != null && tokenExpired == false)
    {
        return _context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("token");
    }

    var authClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Auth");

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
        { "client_id", "my_client_id" },
        { "client_secret", "my_client_secret" }
    };
    var res = await authClient.PostAsync(authClient.BaseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict));

    if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var authentication = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Authentication>(res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        _context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", authentication.Access_Token);

        return authentication.Access_Token;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

This token expires after 60 mins so I have to take care of that as well and I only use this token for accessing one specific endpoint, I dont use this for authentication or authorization. What changes do I make so I can store it in cookie or maybe in localstorage?

Comment: Based on your code and description, it seems that you'd like to check if the client has acquired a token and if the token is expired, for this scenario, as you mentioned, you can store it in cookie or local storage etc. To store it in cookie, you can try the code like this `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", authentication.Access_Token, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expires_in) });`.

Comment: @FeiHan thank you, if add this as the answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What changes do I make so I can store it in cookie or maybe in localstorage?

As we discussed in comments, to store a acquired token in cookie, you can use following code snippet:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", authentication.Access_Token, 
    new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expires_in) });
```

Then you can check if the client has acquired a token and if that existing token is expired in your code logic, like below.

```
var token = "";

if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("token",out token) && tokenExpired == false)
{
    return token;
}
return token;
//...
//code logic here
```